# How to add prefix string to sequence in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

Hi I want to create a sequence in oracle with prefix string. I know how to do this in `MSSQL 2008` but I am new to `oracle`.
Like below

```
ID
======
emp-1
emp-2
```

and so on

Comment: Go for function or stored procedure.

Comment: Can you give me the example

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
create sequence id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
```

and then access sequence set by function not directly:

```
create or replace function get_seq_val() return varchar2 is
begin
return 'ID' || id_seq.nextval;
end;
```

And get value by:

```
select get_seq_val() from dual;
```